# How to use class HashMap to realize Map?

Tags: java, hashmap

[![enter image description here][1]][1][HashMap to realize Map]
Why it doesn't work,when I use class HashMap to realize Map?Anybody,can you give me some advice?

mycode:

```
package com;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Simple1{
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    Map<String,String> map1=new HashMap<String,String>(); 
                       map1.put("1", "A"); 
                       HashMap map2 = new HashMap(); 
                       map2.put("2", "B"); 
                       map2.put("3", "C"); 
                       map1.putAll(map2); 
                       System.out.println(map1);
                }
    }
```

the error warning:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Map cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: `HashMap to realize Map?` Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Read the error on line 5, and you'll probably find an autofix that adds `import java.util.Map;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import both the `Map` interface and the `HashMap` class:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Also, on line 7, you should use generics on your map declaration (like you do on line 5). This only gives you the warning though, not a compilation error.

Comment: But it still doesn't work,and the warning：HashMap cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You need to import both `java.util.Map` and `java.util.HashMap`.

Comment: I have just started studying JAVA，thank you for your warm answer,I will continue to work hard.